# Making of the electricity

Tags: power

I'm interested if there are actually some new electrons created in the process of Making of the electricity (turbine-generator-electricity)?

I guess (flow of the electrons in the wire - electricity) is like a chain reaction once it's started, yes?

If so, where does the electron that starts that process come from?

Answer (score 2):

No electrons are generated. They are just set in motion.

When the wings of a turbine are set in motion, the axis combined with the generator spins. If (very simply speaking to make the logic clear) you place a magnet on this spinning axis and hold a coil of wires close, this moving magnet causes inductive forces on the wire and the electrons start moving.

No electrons are created or removed. They are simply set in motion in some way depending on how you gather and transfer your energy from the outside world and into the electrons in the wire (like the turbine you mention). The wires, wherein you want the electricity to flow, are a part of a circuit. So in some sense the electrons while moving along the wire simply go through a loop forever as long as they are kept in motion by the external force.

Comment: So we could say that the same electrons that started the motion do come back at the source? But aren't they lost in a way (transformed into light, heat etc) I'm not sure how to understand that sentence: No electrons are created or removed. Thanks.

Comment: Nope, electrons are not translated into light or heat or whatever else we use electricity for. You should think of electrons as *carriers* of energy; not as energy themselves. When they are moving, they contain some energy, and when they pass through the material in the light bulb coil, they meet resistance and are *slowed down*. So the electrons are still there, but they now move more slowly. They have passed on some of their energy to the material in the light bulb. (This energy in the material then heats it up, which in the end results in radiation, or light)

Comment: One more thing, just curious, when you mention electricity are you talking about the flow of the of the 29th electron between copper atoms (in a copper wire)?

Comment: Hmm, it's a bit tricky to imagine electrons in the metals in that way. A metal like the cobber wire consists of a lattice of Cu-atoms. And all these atoms bound together in the lattice have sort of a *sea of electrons* surrounding them. Try to imaging that this *sea* is moving and shifting to the side, since the electrons are forced to move.

Material science about how the atoms and electrons are bound together is a whole other story and can be quite tricky :)